# Non existent folder after .php in url does not serve a 404 ( index.php/sdfsf/ )

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I got a problem with my website because every non existent folder or url after a .php file is not treated as a 404.

Example: **https://www.example.com/index.php/non-existent-folder/**

The Example shows a stripped version of my index.php but it should show a 404 or better redirect to the index.php.

I find this bug for every .php file on my website.

Example: **https://www.example.com/my_first_article.php/non-existent-folder/**

How to solve this issue? Because google starts indexing these non existent pages and this results in duplicate content!

I googled but can't find the right search term to find a answer for this problem.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything after a script tag `.php` is added as an environment variable called `PATH_INFO`.

First and foremost, you need to figure out where those links are coming from, Google is getting them from somewhere and you should shut them down, whether it's broken internal links or a bad sitemap, who knows.

You can disable `Accept Path Info` in Apache, or even by adding `AcceptPathInfo off` in your `.htaccess` file.

You can also redirect any visits to scripts that have path info with a `301` or `410` redirect header like so:

```
if( $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ){
    $redirect = current( explode( '.php/', (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]" ) ).'.php';

    header('HTTP/1.1 410 Gone');
    header('Location: '. $redirect);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Hi,
I can not use a php based solution. that would include too much edit. I have to edit every .php file to include this check.
Your "AcceptPathInfo off" does not work.

I tried this one and it seems it does the job, but I don't know if it has any unwanted side effects.

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*).php/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]